# Trying to write patch function for data classes in kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, extension-methods, data-class

Here is my problem.

Let's say we have a `data class` `User`

```
data class User(var name: String? = null, var age: Int? = null)
```

And we have 4 user objects

```
val oldUser = User("user1", 10)
val newUser1 = User("user2", null)
val newUser2 = User(null, 60)
val newUser3 = User(null, null)
```

I want to write an extension function `patch`, that takes 2 `User` objects(or any other data class) and returns a another User which is created by applying patch of second `User`'s non null fields on first.

so for above objects, the patch function should behave like follows -

```
oldUser.patch(newUser1) //returns User("user2", 10) (name is changed)
oldUser.patch(newUser2) //returns User("user1", 60) (age is changed)
oldUser.patch(newUser3) //returns User("user1", 10) (no change)
```

The solution that I could come up with so far involves reflection and modify the receiver `User`. Here is the code for that.

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> T.patch(new: T): T {
    T::class.memberProperties
        .filterIsInstance<KMutableProperty<*>>().forEach { field ->
            field.getter.call(new)?.let { field.setter.call(this, it) }

        }
    return this
}
```

How can I write a generic extension function, that can achieve above behaviour and does not modify the original object?

Comment: Clone the original object into a new one, and change the cloned object